# Django TinyMCE blog post don't format html

Tags: html, django, tinymce

TinyMCE in admin panel is working perfectly but when I go to see the posts I see tags. For example

```
<p style="text-align: right;">asdasdasdasdasdddasdasdasd</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">asdasdadasd</p>
<li>asdasda</li>
<li>sd</li>
<li>asd</li>
<li>asdaa</li>
<li>adasda</li>
<li style="text-align: right;">a</li>
<li style="text-align: right;">asdas</li>
<li style="text-align: right;"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your variable as safe or add [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape).